# Single user login to multiple Nuxt.js websites with Nuxt Auth

Tags: authentication, vue.js, nuxt.js

Hello I'm creating a group of small websites based on Vue.js with the [Nuxt.js](https://nuxtjs.org/) framework

All sites use the same API (different parts of it but for example the auth is the same for all sites)

Now my client asked me to do a single login for all sites and I'm a little bit lost on how to handle this

Currently I'm using the [nuxt-auth](https://auth.nuxtjs.org/) module to handle the users but I won't mind dropping it if I need to code this manually

Right now my configuration in nuxt.config.js for the Auth looks like this:

```
auth: {
      strategies: {
          local: {
            endpoints: {
              login: { url: 'Account/Login', method: 'post', propertyName: 'data.token' },
              user: { url: 'Account/GetBasicUserInformation', method: 'get', propertyName: null },
              logout: { url: 'Account/Logout', method: 'post' }
            },
            tokenType: null
          }
        }
      }
```

Maybe I can store the token info or similar in a cookie and make other sites check for it before doing the session check?

Comment: Are you asking about a single interface that would interact with the different sites?

Comment: Sorry I don't know what you mean, what I need is for example I sign in on "site1", if then I enter to "site2" the site should know I've already logged in to one of the sites so it won't ask me to log again on "site2" as the credentials are the same for both, hope this makes it more clear, thanks!